# How to access parameter variables in django GET?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my urls file, I have

```
urlpattersn = [
    url(r'insight/<id>', views.insights, name=['test'])
]
```

In my views file, I have

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def insights(request, id):
    print id
```

I'm getting a 404 error and it doesn't seem to recognize the  in the url either? How do i format a get request with params?

Comment: You're getting a 404 error when trying to fetch which URL? Note that I miss the ^ at the beginning of your regex pattern. Second, if you're on Django < 2 (1.11), you need to write your pattern like this: `r'^insight/(?P<id>\d+)'`  if your id's are just numbers. If you're on Django >= 2.0, you should use `path` instead of `url` and your pattern should be `insight/<int:id>` without the `r`

Comment: In your url ending / is missing

url(r'insight/<id>/', views.insights, name=['test'])

Comment: and you call url with base_utl/insight/4/ cause 404

Comment: Check if its true and let me know

Comment: i get 404s when I try to access "insights/2" but I can hit "insights/<id>"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
request = self.request
id = request.query_params.get('id')
```

Comment: is the request= self.request necessary?

Comment: Regarding your first comment, you can do either: `id = self.request.query_params.get('id')`

Then, change your url with `url(r'insight/<id>', views.insights, name=['test'])`